# Why does data.table, setting "with" = F, output a data.table when j is a single column?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have data table dt.

```
dt = as.data.table(c(0,1,2,3))
```

I'd like to know why the behavior of dt differs in the following two lines of code.

```
dt[,V1]

dt[,"V1",with=F]
```

Specifically, the first line produces a numeric vector while the second line produces a data.table.

I'd like to build a function that would allow me to retrieve single columns dynamically by passing a string (thus with=F) and use that output in certain other functions. As it is now, the behavior in the latter case can cause an error in some functions, such as ecdf and hist, which don't accept a data.frame or data.table.

Here's a workaround I've made.

```
as.data.frame(dt[,"V1",with=F])[,1]
```

This returns the expected output: a vector which plays nicely with ecdf and hist. It's just a bit messy. Is there any reason why the behavior in `dt[,"V1",with=F]` differs from `dt[,V1]`?

Comment: Because `data.table` is more consistent than `data.frame`. Use `dt[["V1"]]` instead.

Comment: `data.table` doesn't have `drop` variable (unlike `data.frame`).

Comment: I suggest you start with the [Introduction to data.table HTML vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. @eddi I'll use the `[[` syntax for my function. I'm not sure I get the reasoning for returning a data.table for a single column though. When `with = T`, extracting a single column returns a vector, so why not do the same when `with = F` given that this is how data.frame works?

Comment: @AlexanderLi search for all instances of "drop" in the [FAQ](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf) and that will answer all of your questions

Comment: @eddi Thanks, I gave those sections a read over and am satisfied.

Comment: @eddi I saw the FAQ but I did not have the courage to read the paragraph entirely (I probably would have to read it 10 times to understand it a little). I don't think Alexander understood either because the question is why there is a difference of behavior between the two syntaxes, and I do not see any explanation to this nowhere in this page.

Comment: @eddi Your link is dead, the new link is there: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#beginner-faqs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the data.table [FAQ](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf), many users of data.frame experienced errors when they returned a single column from a data.frame without setting `drop=FALSE`. These users expected a single column data.frame output rather than a vector. The default behavior of data.table when `with=FALSE` conforms to these users' expectations.

Comment: OK but that doesn't explain why we do not have this behavior with `dt[,V1]`.

Comment: @JeanPaul the answer is -- for convenience. Often it's preferable to return a vector rather than needing to extract it from a returned `data.table`. By allowing a vector to return in this case, we allow full flexibility for user to return either a column or a table as needed for each case (i.e. `dt[ , V1]` vs. `dt[ , .(V1)]`)